# How to effectively use "using"?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Below is my code:

```
using (pgsqlConnection conn = new pgsqlConnection(connStr))
{

} //automatically Dispose()    
public class v2Connection:IDisposable
{

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //close the connection and release resources
    }

}
```

This is what I have written so far in my Connection class (v2Connection). It is giving error on pgsqlConnection and it is obvious that at present neither I have a class with this name nor an Interface.

I want to add two function: Open and Close. I am not following where should I call Open() and Close()? If I create an interface with the name: IConnection with two methods:

```
int Open();
int Close();
```

How to use this interface in the above code?

Comment: What's the relation between the `pgsqlConnection` and `v2Connection` classes? Btw standard convention dictates that a class name should start with an uppercase letter in C#.

Comment: At present nothing as such. Should I replace pgsqlConnection with v2Connection?

Comment: Why would Open and Close return ints? You're not thinking error codes right?

Comment: I'm curious to know what your thinking behind this is? Are you planning to be able to call `Open()` and `Close()` throughout your application where you need connectivity? If so, I'd strongly recommend against it...

Comment: What error (on pgsqlConnection) ?

Comment: @Chris: I initially just created a static class, but I wanted to improve upon it and want to make it more professional and loose coupled.

Comment: @RPK, thanks. I'm curious by nature and I was just wondering what you were attempting.  I'd be keen to see your final code for this as I think it'd be great...

Comment: You post a declaration of class A and a usage sample of class B. What exactly is the question? Voting to cose as NARQ

Comment: @Henk: Question is that the "using" that I wrote should implement an interface or a class. If interface, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a wrapper for your connection  :

```
using (MyConnectionWrapper conn = new MyConnectionWrapper ())
{

}
```

With MyConnectionWrapper :

```
 public class MyConnectionWrapper : IDisposable
    {

        void OpenConnection();
        void CloseConnection();
        void Dispose();
    }
```

and  in the constructor of your class

```
public MyConnectionWrapper ()
{
    OpenConnection();
}
```

and in the Dispose function :

```
public void Dispose()
{
   CloseConnection();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would follow the pattern used in existing `SqlConnection` classes - `Open` and `Close` can be called on any valid instance (given valid state for those ops of course) but `Dispose` will `Close` the connection if it's not explicitly done in your code on an `Open`-ed conection.

`using` is really orthogonal to this - it's a nicety in the language to ease your task in ensuring underlying unmanaged resources do not get leaked for `IDisposable` objects. In your case, that is essential if the instance is `Open` when it goes out of scope, and encapsulating the instance via `using` supplies the required `Dispose()` call at the right time.

Answer (score 1):

The class `pgsqlConnection` must implement IDisposable interface. This is what the using statement is doing actually, calls the Dispose method automatically.